# Playing sound according the ID

Tags: android, database, eclipse, audio

I've been completing my Android project (fyi, i am a newbie in android programming) until I get stuck with this..

I make an Android application for learning French language.
I successfully make the whole application except the sound.

All I want to do is to connect the words with the sound in my database (connected with field '_id')

First, I have a table name 'kata' which means 'words' in English that contains several words in French

Table kata

1. _id
2. French
3. Indonesia
4. baca (means : how to read)

Then I searched a lot of references in internet and they told me not to save the sound file with numeric. 
So, I have music files like this a.mp3, b.mp3, c.mp3 and so on.

and then I connected with this code..

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private Activity activity;
private List<List<String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private MediaPlayer mp;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, List<List<String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, null);

    speaker.setOnClickListener(this);

    List<String> kata = new ArrayList<String>();
    kata = data.get(position);         //try to fetch records

       final String ambil = kata.get(0);  //try to fetch the word's id
```

}

then I don't know what to do :(

I've tried with

```
speaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                String name="a";
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource("android.resource://com.mroring.belajarperancis/raw/"+name);
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException
                        | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

and it gives me error

```
07-15 21:39:05.469: E/MediaPlayer(25717): error (1, -2147483648)
```

please help me :( I've been trying with all I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more details about your error and can you tell me where is located your sounds in your database or in the file Raw.

If your sounds (a.mp3) is located in the file Raw to reproduce that sound, you need this code.

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);  

 mp.start();
```

In your code try this.

```
speaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            //String name="a";
            try { 
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.a);  
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException
                    | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I don't know where to put it. I am confuse because this class doesn't have onCreate